# Minimum list of files for tcpdf to work

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

The package seems bloated with a size of 19 MiB. Are there unecessary components I can remove to reduce the size?

Does anyone have a minimum list of files required for the examples provided with tcpdf to work?

Answer (score 8):

I have had the same issue, but all i know is you can remove ALL image files in images, remove all fonts except 'helvetica' or whatever you wish to keep, then I just removed folder, tested, another folder, tested, remove file, tested etc. until i had the bear minimum

I hope this helps, i don't have the list on me... actually still using the full installation on my dev server

Comment: Your comment is still relevant 2 years later (TCPDF version 6.0.051, from 2013-12-02) - I just did this same thing, removed everything except the Helvetica files under the `fonts/` folder, all works great. Reduced file-size of the package from 20MB down to 4MB, and now there's only ~40 files, compared to upwards of 350.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal installation of TCPDF:
 - tcpdf_include.php (main for call in require)
 - tcpdf.php (required - library)
 - tcpdf_autoconfig.php (required)
 - config/tcpdf_config_alt.php (for config)
 - tcpdf_barcodes_1d.php (only when use barcode)
 - tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php (only when use barcode)
 - include/barcodes/* (only when use barcode)
 - include/*.php (required)

 - include/*.icc (required)
 - fonts/helvetica.php (main font)
 - fonts/pdfahelvetica.php (main font)
 - fonts/pdfahelvetica.z (main font)
Other fonts, must be add in fonts folder.

Comment: /* require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php'); */ 

require_once('**/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php**');